# Webform Event Registration skips payment processing

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm, payment-processor

Following the tutorial at Civiteacher.com on "How to: Register for Multiple Events With Webform," registering for an event works, but it skips the payment procession section.

Logs report this error:

```
The CiviCRM "participant getoptions" API function returned the error: "The field 'fee_amount' has no associated option list." when called by line 1459 of utils.inc with the following parameters: "Array ( [field] => fee_amount [context] => create [event_id] => Array ( [259-9] => 259-9 ) [role_id] => 1 [options] => Array ( [limit] => 9999 ) [check_permissions] => [version] => 3 ) "
```

This occurs whether I am logged-in or not as well as with the "CiviContribute: access CiviContribute" given to everyone (just for testing purposes!).

Additional information:

- I set-up the Participant Fee by checking the box by "Webform>Civicrm>Event Registration>Registration>Participant Fee"; it is using the "Select options" widget
- The Webform Element is of type "Radio buttons (static)"
- Running Civicrm 4.6.3, Webform 7.x-4.9 and Webform Civicrm integration 7.x-4.10

Additional information - 2:

Using PayPal Standard as the payment processor.

By "skips" I mean submitting the form results in a confirmation page – no chance to enter payment information:

[image: About to submit …]

Above goes directly to this:
[image: After submitting … no chance to enter payment information]

Here's how I've set up the webform participant fee:
[image]

Comment: Can you edit your question to say more about how you set up the "Participant Fee" field? What type of webform element is it?

Also what version of CiviCRM and the webform module are you using?

Comment: I tracked down that error message and it seems unrelated to the actual payment processing. Can you verify that you have a working contribution page set up to embed in the webform, and edit your question to specify which payment processor you are using and what you mean by "skips" e.g. does it accept the users credit card and then ignore it, or is there no place to enter a card at all? A screenshot or two to show how you set up your webform and what the form looks like would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working by recreating the form using 7.x-4.12 version of the Webform CiviCRM Integration module. (Simply upgrading the module and using the existing form would not work.)

In addition, I had to make sure that Webform>Payment Processor had both "Pay Later" and "Credit Card or PayPal" selected. (You'll notice on the screenshot above that only "Pay Later" displays.)